# Cannot upgrade to 16.04 after failed attempt

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade

I have ubuntu 14.04 LTS and it kept jumping out a message asking me to upgrade to 16.04. So one day I clicked "yes". But then, it failed and it said it would restore to the old system (which is 14.04). That's pretty much a success except that one of the startup screen reads "Ubuntu 16.04". So far I haven't noticed other differences. The upgrade error messages are:

```
Could not install 'linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic'  

The upgrade will continue but the 'linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic' package may not be in a working state. Please consider submitting a bug report about it.  
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

Could not install 'initramfs-tools'  

The upgrade will continue but the 'initramfs-tools' package may not be in a working state. Please consider submitting a bug report about it.  
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1  

Could not install the upgrades  

The upgrade has aborted. Your system could be in an unusable state. A recovery will run now (dpkg --configure -a).
```

I figured that at least one of the reasons that the upgrade failed may be due to disk full in `/boot`. So I cleaned it up and tried to upgrade again. But now, I don't know how to do it. The automatic reminder doesn't jump out anymore. I tried command line and the response is as follows:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

So how can I re-enable the upgrade?

Comment: What does `lsb_release -a` output?

Comment: `$ lsb_release -a`  
    `No LSB modules are available.`  
    `Distributor ID: Ubuntu`  
    `Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS`  
    `Release: 16.04`  
    `Codename: xenial`

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like your upgrade was at least partially successful. What did it say failed?

Comment: I added the error message during the failed attempt to the main post above.

Comment: Added an answer which should get you the correct kernel installed at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your upgrade was partially successful except for perhaps the latest kernel.  Since you have now made room in /boot, you can try installing the metapackage `linux-generic-lts-xenial` which will get you the latest xenial kernel.

If other portions of the upgrade didn't succeed, I do not know how to diagnose that.

Comment: Thank you. I think you are right. I run the command as you said and it looks like I have the new version now. I also run `sudo apt-get install initramfs-tools` but it says `initramfs-tools is already the newest version (0.122ubuntu8.1)`. It also says I have a lot of useless packages so I used `sudo apt autoremove` to clean it up.

Comment: Great! Sounds like your system is in good shape now.